# BoundsChecker for memory leaks in C++ Dll

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I have created a Activex Control component(ie abc.ocx);I am using it in Internet explorer 8.0.Now with the help of Bounds checker i want to find out any memory/GDI leaks.Can any one please help me out regarding this.

Comment: What's the question? "Help" is a rather vague request.

Answer (score 1):

rebuild with BoundsChecker instrumentation, enable leaks detection, in VC project properties -> Debugging -> Command (at least in VC2008) specify IE exe, run your project (IE will be started), do what you need to load and test your DLL, close IE, check BoundsChecker output